# How do I find a list of available printers on a specific print server?

Tags: macos, printing

Is there a way to find a list of available printers on a given server like you can on a PC?

For example, my school hosts all of their printers on one server.  When I run windows, I can do a run command for the address of the server (ex. \server.school.edu), and it will open up an explorer window with all of the printers that are available.  However, when I try and connect to the same server via OS X, it simply asks what drives I would like to mount and there is nothing there.

Answer (score 1):

1. go to System Preferences > print& fax.
2. create new printer. Depending on yor version of Mac OS X,either ("+") below list of existing printers,
   or "Set up Printer button" at top of window then click "Add".
3. Choose printer connection type. Either "IP Printer" in the toolbar of "Printer Browser" or "IP Printing" from dropdown menu.
4. In the "Protocol" dropdown menu select "Internet Printing Protocol -IPP".If this does not give you expected results try "Line Printer Daemon-LDP".
5. Enter hostname of printserver in "Address" field,or browse for network printers.

If you are using Mac OS X Leopard

1. as above
2. as above
3. Right click on the toolbar at the top of the window and select "Customize Toolbar"
   drag the "Advanced" icon to the toolbar and select "Done"
4. click on "Advanced" icon and wait.in a bit you can select "Widows" from the "Type" dropdown-menu.
5. enter in the URL textfield
    `smb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@WINDOWSDOMAINNAME/PRINTSERVER/PRINTERSHARENAME`
    or
    `smb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@IPADDRESS/PRINTERSHARENAME`
    or
    `smb://USERNAME@IPADDRESS/PRINTSHARENAME`
6. fill out the other "Name" and "Location" as you prefer
7. You might be asked for a "USERNAME" and "PASSWORD" firts time round.fill these and enable the  "Add this to your keychain" checkbox.

Did this help? You can view other [Related Q&As.](http://www.techyv.com/question-category/apple/apple-desktop)

Comment: This sort of answered what I was looking for.  It at least gave me a little bit better idea of how to search for an answer.  It appears that it's not really possible to "browse" in the same way that I was referring to on OS X, unless I'm missing something.